# Styling DatePicker Android Marshmallow

Tags: android, datepicker, styling, android-6.0-marshmallow

I'm struggling with android calendar styling. It turns out that android 6 ignores calendarTextColor and uses textColorPrimary in order to style day labels as well as textColorSecondary to style day of weeks. I've checked calendarTextColor on android 5 and it works correctly. According to the documentation textColorPrimary is used as Toolbar text color. https://developer.android.com/training/material/theme.html So my toolbar text color is white and I receive white day labels on a white background. How to specify calendarTextColor without touching textColorPrimary for android api 23?

Answer (score 0):

You could make a custom theme for the datepicker and specify text color there

try this

```
<style name="datePickerTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/colorBlack</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/colorBlack</item>
    <item name="android:textColorTertiary">@color/colorBlack</item>

</style>
```

and then you can specify this theme when you call your DatePickerDialog like this

```
final DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener date = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
                              int dayOfMonth) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            myCalendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
            myCalendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear);
            myCalendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);
            String myFormat = "MM/dd/yy"; //In which you need put here
            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(myFormat, Locale.US);
            calendar.setText(sdf.format(myCalendar.getTime()));
        }

    };

    calendar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            new DatePickerDialog(YourActivity.this,R.style.datePickerTheme, date, myCalendar
                    .get(Calendar.YEAR), myCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                    myCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)).show();
        }
    }); 
}
```